# Queue item results back to calling members of api calls

Tags: c#, queue, task

Created a static class that runs an async task in a loop.  Another class exposes an API set of commands.  I've setup a queue within the loop to process called members of the API.   How can I send the results of the queued item back to the member that added the item to the queue and how would I send back any errors?  All this can be done synchronously, don't need to block my loop thread.

Comment: Hi. Would you mind sharing what you've got so far? It's easier to give suggestions then.

Comment: All I can think of is to create a request object for each api call and send them to the queue.   Each request would have an idnumber, action, return type, and maybe parameter types.  Dequeue a request and Run a task or Func<T>, wait for the results and store in a different list.  Then somehow notify the original calling member to get the results from the list.  The result would also be a result object with idnumber, success, failed, return data, or an exception.  How far off is that?

Answer (score 0):

You could specify onError and onSuccess `Actions` that you use to send feedback back to the member that added the item to the queue.